# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type executing package function from anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

Here is my function `func` in my package `A`:

```
create or replace PACKAGE A AS

    type MY_TYPE IS TABLE OF MYTABLE%ROWTYPE;

    FUNCTION func RETURN MY_TYPE;

END A;


create or replace PACKAGE BODY A AS

    FUNCTION func RETURN MY_TYPE IS
        CURSOR myCursor IS
           SELECT * FROM MYTABLE;
           var_cursor MYTABLE%ROWTYPE;
           myParam MY_TYPE;
           i NUMBER := 1;

        BEGIN
           FOR var_cursor IN myCursor
           LOOP
             myParam.EXTEND;
             myParam(i) := var_cursor;
             i := i + 1;
           END LOOP;

           RETURN myParam;
        END func;
END A;
```

I want to call this function.

```
DECLARE
 type my_type IS TABLE OF MYTABLE%ROWTYPE;
 variable my_type;

BEGIN
   variable := A.func();
END;
```

This gives error

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

The types are the same, so what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51590218/266304) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9472048/266304); there are probably others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **same** type, not an identical but separately defined type:

```
DECLARE
 variable a.my_type;

BEGIN
   variable := A.func();
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will not compile. If you use "end " to finish a a function/procedure the so in this case "end func;" Also, you are doing way too much code. No need to LOOP at all, instead use bulk collect.

```
create or replace package body a as

    function func return my_type is
        begin
           select * 
             from mytable;
             bulk collect into myparam;
           return myparam;
        end func;
end a
```